# Execute Statement IF @move command worked

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to search a set of log files to find a specific string.

I cant seem to find a way to execute specific commands, based on if a file was successfully moved. (Which means the string was found in a log file, and was then moved to the folder named “backup”.

Is there any way of doing this? I have tried the error-level commands, but that was not working as I hoped.

```
    C:
C:
cd logfiles
for /F “delims=“ %%G in (‘findstr /m “failure” *.log’) do @move “%%G” backup 
if // any files were successfully moved to backup folder // (
Echo failed log found
) else (
Echo no failures found
)
```

Comment: it seems [you can't check the errorlevel result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19150594/995714) and will have to parse the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to avoid the use of multi-line code blocks wherever possible.

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@set _result=No failures found
@pushd c:\logfiles
@for /F “delims=“ %%G in (‘findstr /m “failure” *.log’) do @move “%%G” backup > NUL 2>&1 || @set "_result=Failed log(s) found"
@echo %_result%
@popd
```

When move fails, it returns 1 and the `@set "_result=Failed log(s) found"` command will be executed, otherwise it won't.  Assuming of course that my lesdyxia isn't acting up today ;).

Comment: Ok, stable now.

Comment: One L for the NUL device.

Comment: I probably have thousands of files named NULL scattered across my hard drives.  Thanks.

Comment: Where's the **`/r`** option with `pushd` documented, and what does it do?

Comment: @Compo, no clue (removed), it certainly doesn't work on my system.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd logfiles
SET "FAILED="
for /F “delims=“ %%G in (‘findstr /m “failure” *.log’) do (
 move “%%G” backup 
 SET "FAILED=Y"
)
if DEFINED FAILED (
```

You can combine a series of commands within parentheses.

```
 for ...) do SET "FAILED=Y"&move “%%G” backup
```

would do the same thing (cascade commands using `&`)

By first `set`ting a variable to *nothing* then `set`ting it to a value when the `move` is performed (and assuming the `move` is successful) then `if defined` will be *true* if a file was moved, and *false* if no files were moved (ie. no `failure` strings were found in the log file.

**BUT**

You are using "smart" quotes, probably in a word-processor. You should use simple quotes using an editor. Batch has problems with non-ANSI files (Notepad is *barely* adequate, try using `editplus` or `notepad++` or another editor.)

Comment: I can’t seem to get the if/else portions of my script to work. I’m not sure the “SET FAILED” parts are working for me.

Comment: Also... I am using a text editor on my machine, so I don’t think I’m running into formatting issues. I posted this question from my phone, so that’s where the poor formatting is coming from.